# remove particular words from $string in php

Tags: php

I have the following string:

```
$string = java-developer-jobs
```

I would like to remove `-` and `jobs` from $string, but I don't want to use str_replace multiple times.

Comment: actually you don't need to invoke `str_replace` multiple times in each individual characters. it can hold multiple replacements also, just use an array, its in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use array as :

```
$toReplace = array('-','jobs');
$with = array('','');
$string = 'java-developer-jobs';

str_replace($toReplace,$with,$string);
```

Comment: You don't need an array for $with

Comment: I now that but that's for the case when you need to replace with something else

Comment: So not *this* case

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` for this.Try something like this:

```
$string = "java-developer-jobs";
$sentence = preg_replace('/\-|jobs/', ' ', $string);
echo $sentence;
```

> `Output: java developer`

**[LIVE DEMO](http://phpio.net/s/1gly)**